# Why std::map takes custom comparator only by lvalue reference?

Tags: c++

I am wondering why STL classes like `map` or `unordered_map` take custom comparator and hasher objects only by const lvalue reference and not by rvalue reference.

```cpp
unordered_map( size_type bucket_count,
               const Hash& hash,
               const Allocator& alloc )
              : unordered_map(bucket_count, hash, key_equal(), alloc) {}

template< class InputIt >
map( InputIt first, InputIt last,
     const Compare& comp = Compare(),
     const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

In most cases it doesn't matter much, because these objects are normally lightweight, but what if they happened to be quite heavy to copy?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>

struct Key
{
    std::string first, second;
    int third;

    bool operator==(const Key& other) const
    {
        return (first == other.first && second == other.second && third == other.third);
    }
};

struct KeyHasher
{
    KeyHasher(int param) : myparam(param) {}
    KeyHasher(const KeyHasher& other) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; }
    KeyHasher(KeyHasher&& other) { std::cout << "move" << std::endl; }
    std::size_t operator()(const Key& k) const
    {
        using std::size_t;
        using std::hash;
        using std::string;

        return ((hash<string>()(k.first) ^ (hash<string>()(k.second) << 1)) >> 1) ^ (hash<int>()(k.third) << 1);
    }

private:
    int myparam = 22;
    // heavy objects...
};


struct KeyComparator 
{
    KeyComparator() = default;
    KeyComparator(const KeyComparator& other) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; }
    KeyComparator(KeyComparator&& other) { std::cout << "move" << std::endl; }
    bool operator()(const Key& lhs, const Key& rhs) const 
    {
        return lhs.third < rhs.third; 
    }
    
    // heavy objects...
};

int main()
{
    std::map<Key, std::string, KeyComparator> map1( KeyComparator{} );      // can't move key comparator
    map1.insert({ {"John", "Galt", 12}, "first" });
    map1.insert({ {"Mary", "Sue", 21}, "second" });

    std::unordered_map<Key, std::string, KeyHasher> map2{ 33, KeyHasher(729) };     // can't move key hasher
    map2.insert({ {"Marie", "Curie", 17}, "radium" });
    
    return 0;
}
```

Was there a rationale not to add overloads like the following:

```cpp
unordered_map( size_type bucket_count,
               Hash&& hash,
               Allocator&& alloc ) {}

template< class InputIt >
map( InputIt first, InputIt last,
     Compare&& comp = Compare(),
     Allocator&& alloc = Allocator() );
```

The same question about allocators which are used in every STL container.

Answer (score 4):

It's a very basic design decision of the standard library to assume that all function objects are small. If they're not, which should be a rare case, responsability is shifted to the client code - you could work with `std::reference_wrapper`, closures that refer to the heavy state somewhere on the heap (think of `[heavyObject = std::make_unique<SomeType>()](...) { /* ... */ }` and so on.

As a reference, see Item 38 in Scott Meyers "Effective STL", named "Design functor classes for pass-by-value":

> STL function objects are modeled after function pointers, so the convention in the STL is that function objects, too, are passed by value (i.e., copied) when passed to and from functions.

Comment: Ok, but why is there a const reference then? If it's designed to be passed by value, I'd expect the declaration to be Compare comp = Compare() rather than const Compare& comp = Compare().

Comment: Good point. I can't really tell. In `libcxx`, the parameter is simply passed to another template `__hash_table`. Maybe it would be an unnecessary pessimization to pass by value for the constructor? Or it's specified with reference parameters to give library implementers more freedom?

Answer (score 0):

In the very common case, [it would be ambiguous](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51720f5aa623462c) which you meant. You could only have those as non-defaulted parameters.

Even if you didn't have defaults for those parameters, you've now doubled an already large number of overloads.

Comment: I think, we could give a default value only to an rvalue reference argument and leave lvalue reference without a default value.

Comment: You could, but many of these overloads predate rvalue references. They haven't been changed because no-one has made a proposal to the standards committee to change them